# Barcode scanner for Android not scanning?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-camera, barcode-scanner

I am working on a bar code scanner for Android using the ADT for eclipse. This is where I got the code. [Simonmacdonald](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/10/barcode-scanner-example-projects.html)

To start with I just wanted to get something that could scan bar codes and QR codes and then I will change it from there to meet my needs, but I haven't been able to get it to actually return a result. I followed the instructions given on the site and it compiles without any errors. I can load it to my device which is a Toshiba Thrive with the latest version of android on it. The tablet itself is 2.5 years old about. It runs fine but it won't scan anything. 
Below is the result from the LogCat from ADT - eclipse.

```
    12-09 11:31:21.900: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Screen resolution: Point(1280, 752)
    12-09 11:31:21.900: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Camera resolution: Point(768, 432)
    12-09 11:31:21.900: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Supported values: null
    12-09 11:31:21.900: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Settable value: null
    12-09 11:31:21.900: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Supported values: [auto, infinity, macro, fixed]
    12-09 11:31:21.900: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Settable value: auto
    12-09 11:31:22.700: E/Camera-JNI(6995): setPowerSave: failed to open, /sys/devices/platform/tegra_camera/power_save_preview: -2
    12-09 11:31:22.700: E/Camera-JNI(6995): Failed to powerSavePreview_start
    12-09 11:31:22.770: D/CameraManager(6995): Calculated framing rect: Rect(340, 176 - 940, 576)
    12-09 11:31:27.600: D/OpenGLRenderer(6995): Flushing caches (mode 0)
    12-09 11:31:27.620: E/Camera-JNI(6995): setPowerSave: failed to open, /sys/devices/platform/tegra_camera/power_save_preview: -2
    12-09 11:31:27.620: E/Camera-JNI(6995): Failed to powerSavePreview_stop
    12-09 11:31:27.640: D/dalvikvm(6995): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 7% free 7165K/7687K, paused 2ms+3ms
    12-09 11:31:27.930: D/PreviewCallback(6995): Got preview callback, but no handler for it
    12-09 11:31:28.240: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Display reports portrait orientation; assuming this is incorrect
    12-09 11:31:28.240: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Screen resolution: Point(1232, 800)
    12-09 11:31:28.240: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Camera resolution: Point(320, 240)
    12-09 11:31:28.250: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Supported values: null
    12-09 11:31:28.250: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Settable value: null
    12-09 11:31:28.250: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Supported values: [auto, infinity, macro, fixed]
    12-09 11:31:28.250: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Settable value: auto
    12-09 11:31:29.050: E/Camera-JNI(6995): setPowerSave: failed to open, /sys/devices/platform/tegra_camera/power_save_preview: -2
    12-09 11:31:29.050: E/Camera-JNI(6995): Failed to powerSavePreview_start
    12-09 11:31:29.110: D/CameraManager(6995): Calculated framing rect: Rect(316, 200 - 916, 600)
    12-09 11:31:29.120: D/OpenGLRenderer(6995): Flushing caches (mode 0)
    12-09 11:31:29.120: E/Camera-JNI(6995): setPowerSave: failed to open, /sys/devices/platform/tegra_camera/power_save_preview: -2
    12-09 11:31:29.120: E/Camera-JNI(6995): Failed to powerSavePreview_stop
    12-09 11:31:29.790: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Screen resolution: Point(1280, 752)
    12-09 11:31:29.790: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Camera resolution: Point(768, 432)
    12-09 11:31:29.810: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Supported values: null
    12-09 11:31:29.810: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Settable value: null
    12-09 11:31:29.810: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Supported values: [auto, infinity, macro, fixed]
    12-09 11:31:29.810: I/CameraConfiguration(6995): Settable value: auto
    12-09 11:31:29.830: D/dalvikvm(6995): GC_CONCURRENT freed 718K, 11% free 6878K/7687K, paused 1ms+4ms
    12-09 11:31:29.830: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(6995): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
    12-09 11:31:30.630: E/Camera-JNI(6995): setPowerSave: failed to open, /sys/devices/platform/tegra_camera/power_save_preview: -2
    12-09 11:31:30.630: E/Camera-JNI(6995): Failed to powerSavePreview_start
    12-09 11:31:30.650: D/CameraManager(6995): Calculated framing rect: Rect(340, 176 - 940, 576)
    12-09 11:31:30.840: D/dalvikvm(6995): GC_CONCURRENT freed 129K, 6% free 7250K/7687K, paused 2ms+3ms
    12-09 11:31:30.840: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(6995): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
    12-09 11:31:30.980: D/dalvikvm(6995): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 669K, 15% free 6682K/7815K, paused 17ms
    12-09 11:31:31.020: D/dalvikvm(6995): GC_CONCURRENT freed 12K, 9% free 7169K/7815K, paused 1ms+1ms
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: have you had a look at [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) yet? they provide 1D & 2D(QR) barcode scanning with sample projects that are very easy to use.

Comment: I couldn't ever get them to work as a stand alone. The all needed another app. I had it working but with the second app.